# Scala Spray redirect to another page/domain after api call

Tags: scala, spray

I have an API call written with Scala/Spray. This is invoked through a form in html/javascript. After the form is submitted I need to redirect to a domain, say www.google.com. I thought about using a meta http-equiv refresh. However it seems to enclose my HTML incorrectly. Is there a more eloquent way of doing this? Ive also attempted with redirect, however it will invoke the redirect prior to completion

```
 val route = {
    respondWithHeader(RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")) {
        post {
          path("somecall") {
            respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) {
            entity(as[MultipartFormData]) { fd =>
              performSomeAction(fd)
            redirect("www.google.com", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently)
            }
          }
        }
```